# jQuery compare height not running on reduction of height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following piece of jQuery checking the height of the left and right side columns. If the alert list (left) increases in height, the sidebar row then also increases in height to match. However, once this has increased, and the alert list is decreased (by selecting a different area or a lower number of alerts) the sidebar and overall row containing everything does not reduce in height, leaving huge space below.

**To replicate the issue:**
    Select ST HELENS area.
    Choose 100 alerts
    Now choose WIRRAL area.
    The containing height does not reduce.

http://178.62.45.247/areas.php

***Note, this must work from IE7 and above ***

```
function areasRowHeight() {
    $height1 = $('.nopr').height();
    $height2 = $('.nopl').height();
    if($height1 > $height2) {
        $('.areasrow').height($height1);
    }
    else {
        $('.areasrow').height($height2);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){     
    $( window ).resize(function() { 
        maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
    });
    $( window).scroll(function(){
        maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
    });
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
        maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
    });
    $('.burgermenu').on('click', function(event){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('.cancel').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('.smnav').css('display', 'block');
        // $('.burgermenu').attr('class', 'burgermenu-open')         
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.cancel').on('click', function(event){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('.burgermenu').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('.smnav').css('display', 'none');
        // $('.burgermenu').attr('class', 'burgermenu-open')         
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.show5').on('click', function(event){
        hide('.latestalerts ul', 5);
        maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
        $('.areasrow').height('auto');
        event.preventDefault();

    });

    $('.show10').on('click', function(event){
        hide('.latestalerts ul', 10);
         maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
        $('.areasrow').height('auto');
        event.preventDefault();

    });
    $('.show100').on('click', function(event){
        hide('.latestalerts ul', 50);
         maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
        $('.areasrow').height('auto');
        event.preventDefault();

    });
    $('.showall').on('click', function(event){
        resetHide();
         maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
        $('.areasrow').height('auto');
        event.preventDefault();

    });        

    var trigger = $('.button li a'),
    container = $('.latestalerts');      
    trigger.on('click', function(event){
    windowAnchor();
    event.preventDefault();       
      var $this = $(this),
      target = $this.data('target');
      $('#content').load('controllers/areaload/' + target + '.php');   
        areasRowHeight();
    });

    maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');

});
```

Comment: IE7? Even IE10 is deprecated today

Comment: Yes however when building something for a public sector they tend to keep to outdated everything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no IE7 but if I right understand you should remove from your `style.css`

```
.areasrow .nopr {
    height: 100% !important;
}
.areasrow .nopl {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.areasrow .nopr .inner-content {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.areasrow .nopl .sidebarbg {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then change in `main.js`

```
$('#content').load('controllers/areaload/' + target + '.php');
areasRowHeight();
```

to

```
$('#content').load('controllers/areaload/' + target + '.php', function(){
  maxHeight('.nopr', '.nopl');
});
```

A bit dirty but with this document structure this is all what I can suggest.